# Graphical Bugs?

Tags: unity, compiz

I been using Ubuntu for awhile now, its a great operating system, both smooth and responsive, but there are some small things that bug me.

1. Rough top window borders. For every windowed application I noticed the rounded corners are not really smooth, is there something I can do to fix this? Like antialias or something to do with Compiz manager?
2. When restoring a window from minimize, theres a white line that flickers for about 1-2 seconds.
3. Google Chrome has no top menu. For other apps, usually when I move the mouse cursor to the top left corner it shows some menus section but for chrome its just blank.

Any ideas on how I can fix these minor but annoying issues?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. What graphics card / drivers are you using?

Comment: but chromium have it ! you can use the open source chrome instead of Google chrome .

Comment: Here's what the system details says: Memory: 3.5 GiB, Processor: Intel Core i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz x 4, Graphics: Intel Ironlake Mobile, OS type: 64-bit, Disk 30.6 GB.

Comment: I enjoy playing casual flash games from time to time, and Chromium's flash integration is not as great as Chrome's PepperFlash

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: 1 and 2 are more likely bugs. 3 is by design.

Comment: @Braiam So because of 1 and 2 you would be suggesting close-> ot->bug? Wrong!

Comment: These should have been 3 separate questions. 1.) Could be solved via another compiz plugin that renders windows boarders, it was very popular when vista introduced Aero. 2.) Would rather be solved by abandoning compiz in one of the next releases with migration to Mir (even more annoying with wobbly windows) 3. Is a missing feature in closed source software -> talk to the vendor.

Comment: can you provide more information about the compiz plugin that fixes the corners issue? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://wiki.compiz.org/Decorators/Emerald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The famous rough edges since Ubuntu 4.10 got it its name "Wart Warthog", and it has not shaken off the original title since.

:-)

I have not tried it yet, but some reviews I have seen claim that the latest version, 13.10 solves it.
See here: http://fossmaniac.hubpages.com/hub/Ubuntu-1310-8-Solid-Reasons-to-Upgrade

On the other hand, comments I have seen in different forums around the Net, claim it still lingers.
For example, here:

### http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/44322/the-ubuntu-situation-linux-unplugged-9/

2) Menu items. It sounds like you are describing the global menu, right?
This is a known bug, see here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221304

and here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306667

Comment: I'm running 13.10 right now and still see the visible and annoying rough edges.